# How to order by ancestor/parent Google App Engine query?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I would like to order entities by ancestor, [GQL reference](http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html) only mentions properties in ordering. Do I have to store a parent as a property to involve it in the ordering?

I trying to achieve something like this:

```
Foo.all().ancestor(bar).order('ancestor').order('-value').fetch(100)
```

EDIT:

I have something like this:

```
bar
 ├ spam
 │  ├ foo2 (value = 2)
 │  └ foo7
 └ egs
    ├ foo6
    └ foo5
```

And I'd like to get: `[foo5, foo6, foo2, foo7]`. I guess what I really want I to group them by ancestor, and then order them by `value` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordering by key will sort first by ancestors, then by the id or name of the entity. If you want to sort by ancestor but not by id/name of the entity itself then yes, you'll need to include an explicit 'ancestor' SelfReferenceProperty to sort on.

Comment: @aptwebapps With `.order('__key__')`.